# BigQuery struct dynamic field names from column value

Tags: sql, struct, google-bigquery, nested, pivot

How can I create a BigQuery struct where the names are dynamic - e.g. values from some column in the data.

As far as I can tell, it's not really possible outside of 2 approaches:

- Using STRING_AGG to dynamically generate some JSON and then convert it after into a STRUCT (although this presents a problem in itself because you can't automatically convert a JSON to STRUCT given STRUCTs are more restrictive than JSONs - you'd have to curate it explicitly.
- Perhaps PIVOT followed by some SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT() cleverness but as far as I can see there's a missing aggregate function in BigQuery for combining structs. When pivoting/grouping data, I expect to be able to aggregate columns into a struct but I see no such possibility to do this.

If I have this source data:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, "foo" AS category, "foo1" AS name, 10 AS value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "foo", "foo2", 20
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "foo", "foo3", 30
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "bar", "bar1", 100
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "bar", "bar2", 200
)
```

I want the output to be:

| id | foo.foo1.value | foo.foo2.value | foo.foo3.value | bar.bar1.value | bar.bar2.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 100 | 200 |

Is it doable or is this a case for javascript UDF?

P.s. don't know what is going on with stackoverflows markdown tables. Renders fine in preview - if someone can edit my text to fix it, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted by partially constructing the JSON for an individual row and then using STRING_AGG during a PIVOT and then building the outer struct with * EXCEPT syntax in the outer select.

The result of this is one can achieve dynamically generated struct keys (it ends up being a PIVOT problem only). I've kept my inner structure as JSON because it will be inconsistent schema across my dataset - if yours wasn't, you could convert back to being a STRUCT.

```sql
WITH `seed` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS `id`, "foo" AS `category`, "foo1" AS `name`, 10 AS `value`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "foo", "foo2", 20
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "foo", "foo3", 30
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "bar", "bar1", 100
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, "bar", "bar2", 200
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS `id`, "foo" AS `category`, "foo1" AS `name`, 10 AS `value`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, "bar", "bar1", 1000
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, "bar", "bar2", 2000
),

`cte` AS (
  SELECT
    * EXCEPT(`name`, `value`),
    CONCAT('"', `name`, '": ', TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(`value`))) AS `partial_json`
  FROM `seed`
),

`output` AS (
  SELECT
    * EXCEPT(`json_foo`, `json_bar`),
    STRUCT(PARSE_JSON(CONCAT("{", `json_foo`, "}")) AS `items`) AS `foo`,
    STRUCT(PARSE_JSON(CONCAT("{", `json_bar`, "}")) AS `items`) AS `bar`
  FROM `cte`
  PIVOT(
    STRING_AGG(`partial_json`, ", ") AS `json`
    FOR `category` IN ("foo", "bar")
  )
)

SELECT 
  `id`, 
  `foo`.`items`.`foo1`.`value` AS `foo1`, 
  `foo`.`items`.`foo2`.`value` AS `foo2`, 
  `foo`.`items`.`foo3`.`value` AS `foo3`, 
  `bar`.`items`.`bar1`.`value` AS `bar1`, 
  `bar`.`items`.`bar2`.`value` AS `bar2`
FROM `output`
```